# Bizarre behaviour of mounted disk (Linux)

Tags: linux, mount, docker

there!

*Is it possible that a volume mounts by itself?* AND *That it "steals" the content from the current mounted volume*. And sorry if I cannot make a more clear question, but here is the issue that I am facing (on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS):

I am using a docker container to run some sequencing analysis, prompting the following line:

```
sudo docker run -v /media/mol/hdmol/gatk_data/:/gatk/my_data -it broadinstitute/gatk:latest
```

So, as one can see here I am mounting a volume in the container from my computer's `/media/mol/hdmol/gatk_data/` folder. `hdmol` is the name of the mounted volume on the machine.

I have been running the container commands and transferring files to the `hdmol` for almost 2 weeks now, without any problem. However, since a couple of days, the commands throw an error in the middle of the process (which according to the repository developer is due to lack of disk space), and no files are saved. The `hdmol` volume has plenty of space left though (~3TB). So, I closed the container and went in to inspect what the problem might be.

And here is what I found:

(1) The `hdmol` volume is there, but this time only with the folder I had mounted on the container. And it seems that the directory is empty:

```
(base) mol@ni-HP-EliteDesk:/media/mol$ ls -lR hdmol
hdmol:
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Dec  5 10:26 gatk_data

hdmol/gatk_data:
total 0
```

(2) However, it seems like another volume has been mounted, namely `hdmol1`:

```
(base) mol@ni-HP-EliteDesk:/media/mol$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec  5 10:26 hdmol
drwxrwx--- 7 mol  mol  4096 Nov 25 10:07 hdmol1
```

(3) And now all the directories and files previously storaged on `hdmol` are now on `hdmol1`. Also, one can see that it has not been mounted by `root`.

```
(base) mol@ni-HP-EliteDesk:/media/mol$ ls -l hdmol1
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root  4096 Oct 24 11:57 various
drwxrwxrwx  5 root root  4096 Nov 20 13:42 gatk_data
drwx------  2 root root 16384 Oct 18 09:55 lost+found
-rw-rw-r--  1 mol  mol   8176 Oct 18 12:53 test.odt
drwxrwxrwx  2 mol  mol   4096 Nov 20 12:15 D_test
```

My questions are: (1) **what has happened?**; and (2) **Can it be fixed (or should it be fixed)?**

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I assume the container runs with id `mol`? Is there a `gatk_data` in `/media/mol/hdmol`? Because given the flags on `/media/mol/hdmol` if it's not there it cannot be created.

Comment: Many thanks, @xenoid! I do run the container as user *mol*. And this is what prompts when I run the container: ```(gatk) root@e77529364727:/gatk# ```. Yes, there is a ```gatk_data``` directory. It still exists, but it is all empty at ```hdmol```; all the content from ```hdmol``` are now sitting at ```hdmol1```. Any idea on what's happened?